# How to save background process getting values in arraylist in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, background-process

I wrote background process getting details like this.

```
 public static List<string> myCollection=new List<string>();
 public static string result=null;
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
     string toastMessage= "Application Memory Usage:" + ((Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage)).ToString();
    myCollection.Add(toastMessage);
    myCollection.ToArray();

    foreach (string item in myCollection)
    {
       result += item.ToString() + ", ";
    }
 }
```

i am getting only latest value in result varieable.But i want to save all usage values.Please tell me ..I want to update these details to server for every one hour.

Answer (score 0):

The background process runs for few seconds only, that's why result isn't preserved.
The solution: At the first line of OnInvoke load result from IsolatedStorage, on the last line of OnInvoke save result to IsolatedStorage.